# Displaying uninterpreted HTML code into a html iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ascii

I want to display a text with CR and tabs (let's say the code is into a var *shtml*) into a iframe without losing the ASCII characters.

```
<!--var shtml-->
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY style="FONT-SIZE: 12.5pt">
   mmm
</BODY>
```

My iframe

```
<iframe rows="5" cols="60" id="tahtml">
</iframe >
```

My JS

```
document.getElementById('tahtml').textContent = shtml; //innerText = shtml;
```

[image]

If I use .*innerText* then the code(shtml) is interpreted in Firefox. If I use .*textContent* the code(shtml) is displayed wihtout the ASCII characters. the jQuery .*text()* dose the same as .textContent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like an `<input>`, a `<textarea>`'s DOM interface ([*HTMLTextAreaElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement)) has a *value*  property, it looks like you want to set this property to `shtml`.

```
document.getElementById('tahtml').value = shtml;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/S3Tzb/)

---

For an `<iframe>` make the *MIME* for the page loaded inside it `text/plain`. This can be done by, for example, fetching an empty `.txt` or setting the *src* to `data:text/pain,`. Then you can do the following

```
// don't collapse whitespace, only needed to be done once
ifrmDoc.documentElement.style.whiteSpace = 'pre';
// set text
ifrmDoc.documentElement.innerHTML = shtml;
```

Where

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('tahtml'),
    ifrmDoc = ifrm.contentDocument || ifrm.contentWindow.document;
```

Of course, you could also do it by

- writing the whole thing as a *dataURI* and pass it as the *src*
  `ifrm.src = 'data:text/pain,' + window.encodeURIComponent(shtml);`
- appending your text using by using DOM methods and text nodes
  `ifrmDoc.body.appendChild(ifrmDoc.createTextNode(shtml))`
  (this would still require `whiteSpace: pre;`)
- making a `<textarea>` or `<pre>` in your `<iframe>`, into which you put `shtml` as *value* or a text node, respectively.

Comment: Sorry for this, but I thought it was simpler with an textarea. I have an iframe.

Comment: Please try to ask the question you really want answered in future.